# PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed exception while connecting memsql ssl db

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, mule, tls1.2

I am trying to connect to SSL MySQL db through mule-soft application, i have the required certs and added the same but i am getting the below error. Please help me out.

---

```
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]  
[Memsql_ssl].TEST.worker.01, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = 
certificate_unknown  
[Memsql_ssl].TEST.worker.01, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2  
[Memsql_ssl].TEST.worker.01, called closeSocket()  
[Memsql_ssl].TEST.worker.01, handling exception: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: **signature check failed** 
[Memsql_ssl].TEST.worker.01, called close()  
[Memsql_ssl].TEST.worker.01, called closeInternal(true)  
ERROR 2017-05-17 16:17:17,268 [[Memsql_ssl].TEST.worker.01] 
org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
```

And what is the meaning of **signature check failed** here?

Answer (score 0):

Does the CN of the certificate matches the hostname you are reaching? Have you entered the IP in the Mule instead of the exactly hostname that states in the certificate? Are you sure you imported the right certificate into the Mule app truststore? You MySQL Server may have different SSL certificates. Regards.